# How to use tf.data.Dataset.padded_batch with a nested shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am building a dataset with two tensors of shape [batch,width,heigh,3] and [batch,class] for each element.  For simplicity lets say class = 5.

What shape do you feed to `dataset.padded_batch(1000,shape)` such that image is padded along the width/height/3 axis?

I have tried the following:

```
tf.TensorShape([[None,None,None,3],[None,5]])
[tf.TensorShape([None,None,None,3]),tf.TensorShape([None,5])]
[[None,None,None,3],[None,5]]
([None,None,None,3],[None,5])
(tf.TensorShape([None,None,None,3]),tf.TensorShape([None,5])‌​)
```

Each raising TypeError

[The docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch) state:

> padded_shapes: A nested structure of tf.TensorShape or tf.int64 vector
>   tensor-like objects representing the shape to which the respective
>   component of each input element should be padded prior to batching.
>   Any unknown dimensions (e.g. tf.Dimension(None) in a tf.TensorShape or
>   -1 in a tensor-like object) will be padded to the maximum size of that dimension in each batch.

The relevant code:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator,tf.float32)
shapes = (tf.TensorShape([None,None,None,3]),tf.TensorShape([None,5]))
batch = dataset.padded_batch(1,shapes)
```

Comment: Does `([None, None, None, 3], [None, 5])` (i.e. a `tuple` instead of a `list` of shapes) work?

Comment: ([None,None,None,3],[None,5]) and (tf.TensorShape([None,None,None,3]),tf.TensorShape([None,5])) results in a TypeError.  Seems it tries to treat entries as int and if that fails it expects int64 and not list or TensorShape.

Comment: That sounds like it should work, but I'd need to see a full reproduction to make sure. Can you either post a complete example and the error message as an edit to the question, or in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues)? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to put together a simple example, please see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14299

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to mrry for finding the solution.  Turns out that the type in from_generator has to match the number of tensors in the entries.

new code:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator,(tf.float32,tf.float32))
shapes = (tf.TensorShape([None,None,None,3]),tf.TensorShape([None,5]))
batch = dataset.padded_batch(1,shapes)
```

Answer (score 1):

[TensorShape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape/) doesn't accept nested lists.  `tf.TensorShape([None, None, None, 3, None, 5])` and `TensorShape(None)` (note no `[]`) are legal.

Combining these two tensors sounds odd to me, though.  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but I'd recommend trying to do it without combining tensors of different dimensions.

Comment: I am trying to collect both training data and classifications in one place.  I could definitely treat them separately but the docs seem to imply that different shapes are allowed.  I wonder if this is a bug/feature-in-the-making...