# create a padded_batch from tf.data.Dataset.from_generator() of different array shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following dataset,

```py
partial_x_train_features = [
    [b'south pago pago victor mclaglen jon hall frances farmer olympe bradna gene lockhart douglass dumbrille francis ford ben welden abner biberman pedro cordoba rudy robles bobby stone nellie duran james flavin nina campana alfred e green treasure hunt adventure adventure'],
    [b'easy virtue jessica biel ben barnes kristin scott thomas colin firth kimberley nixon katherine parkinson kris marshall christian brassington charlotte riley jim mcmanus pip torrens jeremy hooton joanna bacon maggie hickey georgie glen stephan elliott young englishman marry glamorous american brings home meet parent arrive like blast future blow entrenched british stuffiness window comedy romance'],
    [b'fragments antonin gregori derangere anouk grinberg aurelien recoing niels arestrup yann collette laure duthilleul david assaraf pascal demolon jean baptiste iera richard sammel vincent crouzet fred epaud pascal elso nicolas giraud michael abiteboul gabriel le bomin psychiatrist probe mind traumatized soldier attempt unlock secret drove gentle deeply disturbed world war veteran edge insanity drama war'],
    [b'milka film taboos milka elokuva tabuista irma huntus leena suomu matti turunen eikka lehtonen esa niemela sirkka metsasaari tauno lehtihalmes ulla tapaninen toivo tuomainen hellin auvinen salmi rauni mollberg small finnish lapland community milka innocent year old girl live mother miss dead father prays god love haymaking employ drama'],
    [b'sleeping car david naughton judie aronson kevin mccarthy jeff conaway dani minnick ernestine mercer john carl buechler gary brockette steve lundquist billy stevenson michael scott bicknell david coburn nicole hansen tiffany million robert ruth douglas curtis jason david naughton move abandon train car resurrect vicious ghost landlady dead husband mister near fatal encounter comedy horror']]

partial_x_train_plot = [[b'treasure hunt adventure'],
                        [b'young englishman marry glamorous american brings home meet parent arrive like blast future blow entrenched british stuffiness window'],
                        [b'psychiatrist probe mind traumatized soldier attempt unlock secret drove gentle deeply disturbed world war veteran edge insanity'],
                        [b'small finnish lapland community milka innocent year old girl live mother miss dead father prays god love haymaking employ'],
                        [b'jason david naughton move abandon train car resurrect vicious ghost landlady dead husband mister near fatal encounter']]

partial_x_train_actors_array = [[b'victor mclaglen', b'jon hall', b'frances farmer',
                                 b'olympe bradna', b'gene lockhart', b'douglass dumbrille',
                                 b'francis ford', b'ben welden', b'abner biberman',
                                 b'pedro de cordoba', b'rudy robles', b'bobby stone',
                                 b'nellie duran', b'james flavin', b'nina campana'],
                                [b'jessica biel', b'ben barnes', b'kristin scott thomas',
                                 b'colin firth', b'kimberley nixon', b'katherine parkinson',
                                 b'kris marshall', b'christian brassington', b'charlotte riley',
                                 b'jim mcmanus', b'pip torrens', b'jeremy hooton', b'joanna bacon',
                                 b'maggie hickey', b'georgie glen'],
                                [b'gregori derangere', b'anouk grinberg', b'aurelien recoing',
                                 b'niels arestrup', b'yann collette', b'laure duthilleul',
                                 b'david assaraf', b'pascal demolon', b'jean-baptiste iera',
                                 b'richard sammel', b'vincent crouzet', b'fred epaud',
                                 b'pascal elso', b'nicolas giraud', b'michael abiteboul'],
                                [b'irma huntus', b'leena suomu', b'matti turunen',
                                 b'eikka lehtonen', b'esa niemela', b'sirkka metsasaari',
                                 b'tauno lehtihalmes', b'ulla tapaninen', b'toivo tuomainen',
                                 b'hellin auvinen-salmi'],
                                [b'david naughton', b'judie aronson', b'kevin mccarthy',
                                 b'jeff conaway', b'dani minnick', b'ernestine mercer',
                                 b'john carl buechler', b'gary brockette', b'steve lundquist',
                                 b'billy stevenson', b'michael scott-bicknell', b'david coburn',
                                 b'nicole hansen', b'tiffany million', b'robert ruth']]

partial_x_train_reviews = [
    [b'edward small take director alfred e green cast crew uncommonly attractive brilliant assemblage south sea majority curiously undersung piece location far stylize date goldwyn hurricane admittedly riddle cliche formula package visual technical excellence scarcely matter scene stop heart chiseled adonis jon hall porcelain idol frances farmer outline profile s steam background volcano romantic closeup level defies comparison edward small film typically string frame individual work art say outdid do workhorse composer edward ward song score year prior work universal stun phantom opera'],
    [b'jessica biel probably best know virtuous good girl preacher kid mary camden heaven get tackle classic noel coward role early play easy virtue american interloper english aristocratic family unsettle family matriarch kristin scott thomas noel coward write upper class twit pretension wit keep come kind adopt way adopt oscar wilde george bernard shaw kid grow poverty way talent entertain upper class take coward heart felt modern progressive generally term social trend whittakers easy virtue kind aristocrat anybody like hang party invite noel entertain amelia earhart aviation jessica biel character auto race young widow detroit area course area motor car auto race fresh win monte carlo win young ben barnes heir whittaker estates lot land debt barnes bring biel home family mortify classless american way sense recognize class distinction thing get rid title nobility aristocrats story scott thomas dominate family try desperately estate husband colin firth serve world war horror do probably horror trench war slaughter fact class distinction tend melt combat biel kind like wife rule whittaker roost scandal past threatens disrupt barnes biel marriage form crux story turn fact end really viewer figure eventually happen second film adaption easy virtue silent film direct young alfred hitchcock easy virtue actually premier america london star great american stage actress jane cowl guess coward figure american heroine best american theatergoer british one version easy virtue direct flawlessly stephen elliot fine use period music noel coward cole porter end credit really mock upper class coward tradition play going gets tough tough going believe elliott try say class especially one right stuff course obligatory fox hunt upper class indulge oscar wilde say unspeakable uneatable chance younger generation expose noel coward worth see'],
    [b'saw night eurocine event movie european country show day european city hear le bomin barely hear derangere la chambre des officiers fortunately surprise discover great talent unknown large audience derangere absolutely astonish play character antonin verset victim post wwi trauma live trouble scene endure month war cast excellent great work cinematography offer really nice shot great landscape stun face edit really subtile bit memory make sense story minute movie show real chill ww archive action flick like sensitive psychologic movie really think absolutely recommend les fragments d antonin let le bomin'],
    [b'rauni mollberg earth sinful song favorite foreign film establish director major talent film festival circuit get amazing followup milka base work novelist timo mukka till worthy major dvd exposure unlike kaurismaki bros follow double handedly create tongue cheek deadpan finnish film style fan world mollberg commit naturalistic approach film overflow nature life lust earthiness find scandi cinema mainly work famous talent swede vilgot sjoman curious yellow fame director film tabu title imply mollberg effort quite effective sidestep fully treat screen theme incest making adult character father figure real blood relate daddy applies usual merely step father gimmick use countless time american movie incest work matti turunen kristus perkele translate christ devil really common law step dad underage milka beautiful offbeat fashion young girl portray shot irma huntus bring screen sexiness bergman harriet andersson decade earlier create international success summer monika sawdust tinsel imagine actress milka role shame do pursue act career afterward completing strong line leena suomu earth mother type confines act narrow emotional range prove solid rock crucial role bookended spectacularly beautiful shot birch wood winter virtually black white visually color presence milka film quickly develop nature theme presence strange click beak bird talisman early scene milka handyman turunen frolicking naked lake emerge oh natural sex play year old milka man result tastefully shoot intimacy imply ejaculation set trouble come religious aspect remote farm community heavily stress especially enjoy motif spiritual guidance cantor malmstrom quality anti stereotypical play eikka lehtonen instead rigid cruel turn care milka illegitimate baby bear strong romance turunen stud continue service mom woman neighborhood present utterly natural viewer position watch ethnographic exercise moralistic tale powerful technique milka frequently speak directly camera viewer forceful monologue bear crisp sound record sound nature include rain constant motif make milka engross experience view film subtitle knowledge finnish lapp recall best silent era classic direction strong convey dramatic content theme way transcend language kudos mollberg talented cinematographer job work remain obscurity ripe rediscovery'],
    [b'wonder horror film write woody allen wannabe come like check imaginatively direct typical enjoyable haunt place premise solid makeup effect good job major flaw dialogue overload cheeky wisecrack witticisms sample want scary shopping ex wife hit mark deliver inappropriate moment hero battle evil ghost']]

partial_y_train = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]  # multilabel classification
```

As you can see they represent arrays of different shapes and I use the Dataset.from_generator() API to create a tensor with those 4 arrays + 1 target value.

```py
def generator():
    for i in range(0, len(partial_y_train)):
        # creates x's and y's for the dataset.
        yield b''.join((partial_x_train_features[i] + partial_x_train_plot[i] + partial_x_train_actors_array[i] + partial_x_train_reviews[i])), partial_y_train[i]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, (tf.string, tf.int64),
                                         (tf.TensorShape(None), tf.TensorShape([17])))
```

Since the arrays in each Tensor do not have the same shape, I thought the padded_batch approach with a fixed padded_shape.

However, when I try the following code I get an error `ValueError: Padding value should be a scalar, but is not: tf.Tensor([0], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)`

```py
dataset=dataset.padded_batch(32, padded_shapes=((50),[None]), padding_values=(([0], [17])), drop_remainder=True) # I want each array to have size 50 and the remaining integers to be 0 if the length of the array is not 50.
```

You can also follow my [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sYRgWmLSFWNJvTlQrkdIfFHt2rUZ97IB?usp=sharing) to replicate the issue for yourself. Also, note that I have found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103249/how-to-use-tf-data-dataset-padded-batch-with-a-nested-shape) but doesn't seem to answer my question. Please write in the comments if there is a similar question.

Comment: Try changing `padding_values=(([0], [17]))` to `padding_values=((' ', tf.constant(17, tf.int64)))`

Comment: @GPhilo I get this error TypeError: Padding value tensor (tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int32)) does not match output type: <dtype: 'string'>

Comment: Yes, I saw afterwards that the types were different. See the edited comment. With those values, in your colab it works now (I am not sure if it works as you expect, but the items are padded. You may have a logic error there, though).

Comment: @GPhilo Yeah It seemed to work but I cant print the data inside dataset ```for i, j in dataset.take(5):
  print(i)
  print(j)```

Comment: @GPhilo If you are on my colab notebook you will see a comment of mine!

Comment: @GPhilo the batch generated seems to be empty my dataset is not (check the notebook)

Answer (score 0):

here again. You can utilize the [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/bucket_by_sequence_length) `bucket_by_sequence_length` to make your batches of different length.

The code will be like this.

```
# This function determines the length of the sentence.
# This will be used by bucket_by_sequence_length to batch them according to their length.
def _element_length_fn(x, y=None):
    return array_ops.shape(x)[0]


# These are the upper length boundaries for the buckets.
# Based on these boundaries, the sentences will be shifted to different buckets.
boundaries = [df.headline.map(len).max() - 850, df.headline.map(len).max() - 700, df.headline.map(len).max() - 500,
              df.headline.map(len).max() - 300, df.headline.map(len).max() - 100, df.headline.map(len).max() - 50,
              df.headline.map(len).max()]

# These defines the batch sizes for different buckets.
# I am keeping the batch_size for each bucket same, but this can be changed based on more analysis.
# As per the documentation - batch size per bucket. Length should be len(bucket_boundaries) + 1.
# https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/bucket_by_sequence_length
batch_sizes = [batch_size] * (len(boundaries) + 1)

# Bucket_by_sequence_length returns a dataset transformation function that has to be applied using dataset.apply.
# Here the important parameter is pad_to_bucket_boundary. If this is set to true then, the sentences will be padded to
# the bucket boundaries provided. If set to False, it will pad the sentences to the maximum length found in the batch.
# Default value for padding is 0, so we do not need to supply anything extra here.
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.bucket_by_sequence_length(_element_length_fn, boundaries,
                                                                       batch_sizes,
                                                                       drop_remainder=True,
                                                                       pad_to_bucket_boundary=True))
```

You can follow the tutorial I wrote on [this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/tutorial-on-bucket-by-sequence-length-api-for-efficiently-batching-nlp-data-while-training-20d8ef5219d7), this will help you understand how to use the API.

In short, the API will create buckets of different lengths based on your dataset. This helps to reduce memory footprint make your code run efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Prateek. However, I have a question. The term "df" above what is about? because I don't have a similar object on my example.